# Storing user data to Firebase ends up storing the wrong user

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Hi im trying to store user information when a user is created, but with this js code it takes the first registred user´s data insted of the user that was just created..

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://***.firebaseio.com/");

$('.btn').click(function(e) { 
    var isNewUser = true;
    e.preventDefault()
    var mail = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var pass = $('#inputPassword').val();
    ref.createUser({
       email : mail,
       password : pass
    }, function(error) {
       if (error === null) {
          console.log("User created successfully");
       } else {
          console.log("Error creating user:", error);
       }
       ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
          if (authData && isNewUser) {
             ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set(authData);
          }
       });
   });
   return false; //Extra insurance
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is just creating the new user, but the user is not automatically logged on. To quote the [Firebase documentation on creating user accounts](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-creating-accounts):

> Creating an account will not log that new account in.

So the `onAuth` event will **not** fire when the new account is created, but only once the user logs in (or logs out).

Before version 2.0.5 of the Firebase JavaScript library, you had to programmatically log the newly created user on to get access to their `authData`. Your code is not doing that.

You can fix it by logging the user in and setting up the user data in *that* callback:

```
ref.createUser({
   email : mail,
   password : pass
}, function(error) {
   if (error === null) {
      ref.authWithPassword({ email: mail, password: pass }, function(error, authData) {
          if (authData) {
              ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set(authData);
          }
          ref.unauth();
      });
   } else {
      console.log("Error creating user:", error);
   }
```

});

Since [version 2.0.5](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html), the `authData` is also passed into `createUser` callback function as a second argument. So you can also just do:

```
ref.createUser({
   email : mail,
   password : pass
}, function(error, authData) {
   if (error === null) {
      console.log("User created successfully");
      if (authData) {
         ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set(authData);
      }
   } else {
      console.log("Error creating user:", error);
   }
});
```

Strangely enough I only get the `uid` with that last snippet while testing it. If that is not enough for your use-case, you can stick to the first snippet.

Comment: Great answer! "The onAuth event will only fire once the user logs in." -- not entirely true, `onAuth()` fires any time the authentication state changes. It will also fire with an initial state (possibly `null`) after the listener is first attached.